# Gerund and infinitive for subject

Tags: meaning, difference

I have a question about using gerunds and infinitives as a subject.
I know it's possible to say:
**Having a home is good** or **To have a home is good**
But my question is: Can I say it with a base form?
For example: **Have a home is good.**

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: No, you cannot. Also I would strongly prefer putting the verb first when using the infinitive: **It is good to have a home.**

Comment: Ohhhh thank you, my teacher told me they use the “base form” in these cases for giving an order or for imperative like: Eat ice cream, it's delicious. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it's clear.

Comment: "Eat ice cream, it's delicious." is NOT a sentence.

Comment: Ohhh, so what is it then?